# My projects are turning into my background

Tags: rendering, shaders

For some reason my project in material and render views are trying to copy my background, literally. I've tried installing reinstalling (My blender version was 2.83 now is 2.91) google, updating drivers, restarting my computer, starting a new project( it affects even my default cube), resetting my default settings, opening another project and I'm lost...

My computer has 15.9 gb for ram and it's a 2019 CyberPowerPC

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297?sort=newest